# Resetting index of Pandas Series with a lambda expression

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, lambda, series

I have a Pandas series, ts.

```
Date
2020-06-02    10.02
2020-06-03    10.45
2020-06-04    10.95
2020-06-05    11.23
```

For plotting purposes, I convert the index into strings by first converting it into a dataframe. Then apply a lambda expression followed by extracting it out as a Pandas series.

```
dfn = ts.to_frame()
dfn.index = dfn.reset_index().apply(lambda x: x['Date'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), axis=1)
tsn = dfn.iloc[:, 0]
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `rename` with lambda function for cgange format of index:

```
ts = ts.rename(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Or another idea is use `Series` constructor with [`DatetimeIndex.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html):

```
ts = pd.Series(ts.to_numpy(), index=ts.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

---

```
print (ts)
Date
2020-06-02    10.02
2020-06-03    10.45
2020-06-04    10.95
2020-06-05    11.23
dtype: float64

print (ts.index)
Index(['2020-06-02', '2020-06-03', '2020-06-04', '2020-06-05'], dtype='object', name='Date')
```